# How do I remove the lowest n numbers in a numpy array and keep track of its index?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray

Basically I have two numpy arrays which are the same size, lets say:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([0, 3, 1, 2, 5])
b = np.array([1, 3, 8, 7, 8])
```

And if I delete the 2 lowest numbers in NumPy array a but also want to delete the corresponding indexes in b -- how would I go about this?

Desired Result of `print(a),print(b)` after deleting:

```
[3, 2, 5] 
[3, 7, 8]
```

Comment: Is it important to preserve the order of the elements that are kept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to find the index of the minimum, and then remove that value in both lists. The following should work, where steps refers to the number of elements you want to remove.

```
steps = 2
for i in range(steps):
    index = np.where(a == min(a))
    np.delete(a, index)
    np.delete(b, index)
```

Comment: What if you have multiple of the same minimum? Also I do not think .index is an attribute for bumpy array

Comment: I just realized that the code was referring to arrays and not lists. I modified my code accordingly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`numpy.argsort`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) to get the sorted indices of a particular array (by default, in ascending order). Remove the first `n` indices and then sort the indices using `sorted`:

```
n = 2
indx = sorted(np.argsort(a)[n:])
```

Use `indx` to mask both the arrays.

Example:

```
# Generate sample arrays
b = np.arange(7)
a = np.random.choice(b, size = b.size, replace = False)

# b = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6], a = [3 6 0 4 2 5 1]

# Generate indices
n = 2
indx = sorted(np.argsort(a)[n:])

# Mask
>>> b[indx]
[0 1 3 4 5]
>>> a[indx]
[3 6 4 2 5]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try numpy delete method, to delete elements by index.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
index = [2, 3, 6]

new_a = np.delete(a, index)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic method that uses `pop()` and `enumerate()`:

```
a = [0, 3, 1, 2, 5]
b = [1, 3, 8, 7, 8]

count = 0
for i,v in enumerate(a): # For index, value in a...
    if v == min(a) and count < 2: # If the value from that iteration is the smallest number and the amount of numbers removed so far is less than 2...
        a.pop(i)
        b.pop(i)
        count += 1

print(a)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 5]
[3, 7, 8]
```